# W8.1 won't boot "Your PC did not start correctly", Startup Repair error : "root cause found: registry is corrupt"

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, windows-registry

My PC (Windows 8.1, dual booting with Windows 10 Dev Preview) won't boot, every time I try it just goes to Automatic Repair which always fails.
Things I tried:

1. Safe mode doesn't work (goes to Automatic Repair).
2. `sfc /scannow` doesn't work (message: There is a system repair pending ...)
3. `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=d: /offwindir=c:\windows` didn't work either. (message: Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.)
4. I did `chkdsk /r c:` twice didn't find any errors.
5. Tried Startup repair with installation USB a couple of times, most recent one said "root cause found: registry is corrupt"
6. When I first tried System Restore I was able to see restore points (the latest restore point was a windows update of the 13th but it didn't let me restore saying that I need to enable the system protection, my PC stopped working on the 14th) but I can't see any restore points.
7. Refresh doesn't work. (message: There was a problem refreshing your PC. No changes were made)
8. `bootrec /fixmbr, bootrec /fixboot, bootrec /rebuildbcd` none of them worked.

I do have registry back ups, but I'm not sure how to do a restore if I can't go to safe mode. Is there anything else I should try before giving up and reinstalling?

Comment: Could you check your boot disk mode in BIOS settings: IDE or AHCI mode? or RAID mode?

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks for the reply. It says Native IDE.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?, I have the same problem

Comment: @MinaSamy No, not yet, I'm close though. I found a backup of my registry, but when I restored it, the blue loading Windows flashes then goes to automatic repair. I'll update the post if I find the solution.

Comment: Well, I had to do a fresh install, re partitioning the hard disk as in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvoYCdHvJSc

Comment: @MinaSamy I see, I'll do that too if I can't get it to work.

Comment: Sounds like the same situation I found myself in when I asked [Is it possible to enable System Protection from the command prompt?](http://superuser.com/questions/861170/is-it-possible-to-enable-system-protection-from-the-command-prompt).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP gave up and reinstalled OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve the problem so I reinstalled the OS. But I did a fresh install over the non-working W8.1 so that my stuff will be stored in Windows.old so that I can retrieve them later.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same thing yesterday.
When booting, select the "advanced" option, and you can get to system restore.
Choose a restore point at least a few days before the problem.

This worked and got me running again, but the overnight automatic update broke it again.

I repeated the system restore, this time disabled the automatic update, as it now automatically breaks the system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I when I go to System Restore I don't see any restore points :(