# Win Ten cannot repair

Tags: windows-10, boot, repair

I cannot reply to this thread: [Is it possible to enable System Protection from the command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/861170/is-it-possible-to-enable-system-protection-from-the-command-prompt/862115#862115?newreg=4cd4eab44b2b42afbd1c075e999ef5e3)

I have the exact same problem, but when I tried:

```
ren SYSTEM system.001
ren SOFTWARE software.001
```

...I was able to rename the SYSTEM file, but when I tried to rename the SOFTWARE file, it says:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I tried `Takeown /F` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Fill out your profile and you can comment, but, these aren't threads with ongoing conversations here, they are simple Question-Answer pages. Your question is unique and deserves its own place: http://superuser.com/help/privileges

Comment: Did you do that form a running windows or repair shell thing? Did you try it in safe mode?

Comment: You shouldn't be replying to an old question with "I have this problem too." People doing that is why it got locked. What you should do is ask your own question (as you have done) and tell us what your problem is and what didn't work. Try to make your question self-contained but link to other sources to show that your question is similar but distinct from the original question. You can [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1147074/edit) your question to provide more information. It might also be worth taking the [tour] to see how thing here are different from a forum.